# MySQL Select columns where the column name contains a substring

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a lot of fields about a person and then several recommendations of other people.

They are named:

"`recommendation_1_name`" "`recommendation_1_company`" '`recommendation_1_contact`" 
"`recommendation_2_name`" "`recommendation_2_company`" "`recommendation_2_contact`" 
and so on.

I am trying to come up with a statement that allows me to only get the recommendations.

I imported an excel file into the table so it's just one large table.

This is what I have and it is returning an Empty set.

```
select * from questionnaire where 'COLUMN_NAME' like '%recommendation%';
```

I've been playing around with it making a table with only the recommendation fields and it still doesn't return anything.

Comment: You might want to add details about what programming language you are using with MySQL. You could generate the query dynamically. Also, it's important to note that the design of your database is wrong. If you can change it, you should!

Comment: **Normalize** your data.

Comment: Please do some normalizations

Comment: Even I think you realldy should change your layout as metnioned by @PM77-1, you might want to check dynmic sql

Comment: I was hoping there was a short cut because the excel file is so large it would take a while to rearrange it and normalize it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mysql: select recommendation_1_name, recommendation_2_name etc... from (table) where (USER) = (USERID) or however you can uniquely identify that user.

Answer (score 0):

This Query generates you dynamic a SELECT query with all fields like 'recommendation%'. You only must setup the Databasename, and the Tablename. You can directly query the result of my query or add the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT( 'SELECT ',
    GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ',\n')
  )
  FROM information_schema.columns 
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DBNAME' 
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLENAME' 
  AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'recommendation%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to normalize your schema.

But just as an experiment and example for some other cases (maybe somebody really need it). Here is solution to get this case resolved using stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_recommendations`()

BEGIN
DECLARE Q VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE C_NAME VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) as `columns`
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' 
  AND TABLE_NAME ='questionnaire'
  AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE  '%recommendation%'
;

SET Q  = 'SELECT ';

OPEN cur;
   FETCH cur INTO C_NAME;
   SET Q = CONCAT(Q,C_NAME,' ');
CLOSE cur;

SET @Q = CONCAT(Q,'FROM questionnaire;');

 PREPARE stmt FROM @Q;
 EXECUTE stmt ;

END
```

Don't forget to replace `TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'` with your real database name.